# Convert a single byte to a string?

Tags: java, android, type-conversion

This is simply to error check my code, but I would like to convert a single byte out of a byte array to a string. Does anyone know how to do this? This is what I have so far:

```
recBuf = read( 5 );
Log.i( TAG,  (String)recBuf[0] );
```

But of course this doesn't work.

I have googled around a bit but have only found ways to convert an entire byte[] array to a string...

```
new String( recBuf );
```

I know I could just do that, and then sift through the string, but it would make my task easier if I knew how to operate this way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can make a new byte array with a single byte:

```
new String(new byte[] { recBuf[0] })
```

Answer (score 9):

Use `toString` method of `Byte`

```
String s=Byte.toString(recBuf[0] );
```

Try above , it  works.

**Example:**

```
 byte b=14;
String s=Byte.toString(b );
System.out.println("String value="+  s);
```

**Output:**

```
String value=14
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a `String` constructor of the form `String(byte[] bytes, int offset, int length)`. You can always use that for your conversion.

So, for example:

```
    byte[] bite = new byte[]{65,67,68};

    for(int index = 0; index < bite.length; index++)
        System.out.println(new String(bite, index,1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
Hows about

```
""+ recBuf[0];//Hacky... not sure if would work
((Byte)recBuf[0]).toString();
```

Pretty sure that would work.

Answer (score 0):

What about converting it to char? or simply

```
  new String(buffer[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

public static String toString (byte value)

Since: API Level 1
Returns a string containing a concise, human-readable description of the specified byte value.

Parameters
value   the byte to convert to a string.
Returns
a printable representation of value.][1](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Byte.html#toString%28byte%29)
this is how you can convert single byte to string try code as per your requirement

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Byte.html#toString(byte) try this link

Answer (score 0):

Another alternate could be converting `byte` to `char` and finally `string`

```
Log.i(TAG, Character.toString((char) recBuf[0]));
```

Or

```
Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf((char) recBuf[0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming that you're using 8bit character encoding (like ASCII) and this would be wrong for many others.

But with your assumption you might just as well using simple cast to character like

```
char yourChar = (char) yourByte;
```

or if really need String:

```
String string = String.valueOf((char)yourByte);
```